# On mac with Eclipse + tomcat not able to load config files

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web

I am using Mac.

I am trying to run web application in Eclipse on tomcat server. I am getting the following error

log4j:ERROR Could not parse file [../config//log4j.xml].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/../config/log4j.xml

java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../conf/aut.properties

where should I keep the these files? so that I can run web application on tomcat inside eclipse?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching application, log4j.xml should be in your resources folder in your app, since this configs are used inside of your code to log things.

project -> src -> main -> resources -> log4j.xml